# Trying to create DataTable object but getting jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

Trying to create DataTable object but getting error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 
    at isArraylike (http://localhost:9100/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:539:27)
    at Function.jQuery.extend.map (http://localhost:9100/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:461:14)
    at _fnFilterCreateSearch (http://localhost:9100/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js:3000:14)
    at _fnFilter (http://localhost:9100/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js:2936:18)
    at _fnFilterComplete (http://localhost:9100/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js:2838:4)
    at _fnReDraw (http://localhost:9100/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js:2090:4)
    at _fnInitialise (http://localhost:9100/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js:3280:3)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9100/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js:6521:5)
    at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://localhost:9100/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:374:23)
    at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (http://localhost:9100/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:139:17)
```

The declaration of the DataTable is such as

```
var oL = angular.element('#orderList');
var dt = oL.DataTable();
```

The second line is where the error is thrown.

Comment: My guess would be that `oL` isn't a valid object type for Datatables. http://www.datatables.net/manual/data#Data-source-types

Comment: What version if dataTables? 1.10.0, 1.10.1 or ...?

Comment: I'm using DataTables as an angular module. The bower.json file for this module specifies:

    "dependencies": {
        "angular": ">=1.3.0",
        "jquery": ">=1.11.0",
        "datatables": ">=1.10.0"
    }